# Python and pywinauto while automate with software

Tags: python-2.7, window, pywinauto

I am facing problem.
Currently, I have install window on my MacBook Air 64bit. By right, it supposed to be 64bit window but it turned out to be 32bit window instead. As the System directory showed c:/windows/system32.

With that, I install python 32bit, pywin32 and pywinauto. However, I want to automate a software that is 64bit and it currently working on my window 32bit.

My question: is it okay for me to use python 32bit and pywin32 and pywinauto to automate a 64bit software?

or should I change my python to 64bit,pywin32-amd64 and pywinauto to automate a 64bit software when my window is at 32bit but my processor is 64bit.

I have try to change window to 64bit but it just couldn't work as I reformate the whole laptop and reinstall macOS and reinstall window to 64bit. it just change out to be 32 bit.

Comment: The folder system32 always exists even for 64-bit Windows. 64-bit app won’t work in 32-bit OS. Just use function pywinauto.sysinfo.is64bit() or something like that to check OS architecture.

Comment: sorry to ask you again, you are saying that I should install python-2.17.14.amd64, pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7 and pywinauto-0.6.4? For my System directory showed c:/windows/system32. Because I am running an application of 64bits.

Comment: Yes, that’s OK. system32 is 64-bit in 64-bit Windows. A bit confusing for non-Windows users.

Comment: Command “C:\PythonXX\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto” will install all dependencies including pyWin32 so you need only Python and this command to install.